# replace anchor tag with name of anchor tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to replace String

```
var str =' <a name="tom">test</a>+<a name="jerry">test</a>';
```

to tom+jerry

like this we can have many

```
var str = '<a name="tom">test</a>+<a name="jerry">test</a><a name="tom">test</a>+<a name="jerry">test</a>';
```

then output should be `tom+jerrytom+jerry`

Comment: What have you tried? You'll get much better responses if you give some example code and explain what's going wrong.

Comment: jQuery ? or without ?

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: using jquery  out will be `tom+jerry` in 1st case AND `tom+jerrytom+jerry` in 2nd case

Comment: so select them, use each(), use text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming what you want is to have the 'name' attribute be the text:

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i< tags.length; i++) {
    tags[i].innerHTML = tags[i].getAttribute('name');

}
```

if you want the result in a string..

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
function resultInString() {
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i< tags.length; i++) {
        result += tags[i].getAttribute('name') + " + ";
    }

    return result;
}
```

here's the regex if this is all a string:

```
var r = /name="([\w\d]+)"/g
var html = '<a name="tom">test</a>+<a name="jerry">test</a>';

function getString(html) { 
    var match;
    var result;
    while (match = r.exec(html)) {
        result += match[1];
    }
    return result;
}
getString(html);
```

Comment: `<a name="tom">test</a>+<a name="jerry">test</a>` is a string i need a string tom+jerry

Comment: the whole thing is a string? or just the end result is needed as a string?

Comment: `var myhtml = '<a name="tom">test</a>+<a name="jerry">test</a>'` string

Comment: OK, in that case you'd want to go with rgex

Comment: @bpbhat77 look at the update to my answer, let me know if that's what you looked for..

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to use jQuery, because of the jQuery Tag.
Here is an jQuery example of how you could do this:

```
$('a').each(function(){//Foreach anchor
    var name = $(this).attr('name');//get the value of the name attribute of the anchor
    $(this).text(name); //write the value in the anchor as text
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rae79/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$('a').text(function(){
   return this.getAttribute('name');
});
```

---

There is no need of loops to achive this, you can use `.text()` method with a callback function which returns the attribute `name` of current anchor.

---

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ChTHQ/)

---

*As per your comment : i want string in a variable*

```
var htmlstr = '';
$('a').each(function(){
   htmlstr += $(this).get(0).outerHTML;
});
```

Comment: I will delete my answer, its not worth answering as he is confused himself..

Comment: @Mr.Alien Seems to be like this, _really confused himself_.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need an unique list of values, no matter how weirdly the problem was stated:
Use hash map:

```
var uniqueValueMap = {};

$( 'a[name]' ).each( function( idx, elem ) {
    var nameValue = elem.attr( 'name' );
    uniqueValueMap[ nameValue ] = nameValue;
} );

console.log( 'Unique names:', uniqueValueMap );

// "Casting" hash to an array and making a joined string
var arrayOfValues = Array.prototype.slice.call( uniqueValueMap );
var stringOfLife = arrayOfValues.join( '+' );

console.log( 'Final result:', stringOfLife );
```

In case of identical names it will use the latest occurence, not the first one. To turn this behaviour over you'll need to add a check after `var nameValue...`, like this:

`if ( uniqueValueMap.hasOwnProperty( nameValue ) ) continue; //this could be (return true;) instead of (continue;) for "jquery.each" loops. I just don't remember, sorry for inconvience`